# How to get seperate log files for each module while using maven -T option

Tags: maven, logfiles, parallel-builds

My project structure is as follows :

```
Main_Proj
       - pom.xml
       - Component1
                - pom.xml
       - Component2
                - pom.xml
       - Component3
                - pom.xml
```

I have three independent components . I am building them in parallel using the maven threading option i.e `mvn -T 4C install | tee log.txt`.

When i issue the the above command in parent pom directory , it starts building all the three components in parallel , but I end up getting log of all the components in single file in random order and it becomes difficult to debug in case of errors as the number of components is going to increase in future .

So is there any way to get log of each component separately in this case ?